# org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "X" not found on view + H2 Database 1.4.190 + Hibernate 4.2.0.Final

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc, h2

I was running my unit tests directly with the targetted Database which is : Oracle 10g and i was asked to run them under H2 Database.

So, after generating the differents SQL scripts and configured the H2 database (through XML config. with Spring), i realized that some of my tests failed whereas some of them passed...

I have the following view (a view of a view) which returns different columns :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW ##.VIEW_OLB_SAT_COVERAGE
(
   SAT_CODE,
   ORBITAL_POSITION,
   COVERAGE_DOWN,
   COVERAGE_UP
)
AS
     SELECT DISTINCT sat_code,
                     orbital_position,
                     coverage_down,
                     coverage_up
       FROM ##.VIEW_OLB_TXP_COVERAGE
   ORDER BY sat_code ASC;
```

The view "VIEW_OLB_TXP_COVERAGE" is the following :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW ##.VIEW_OLB_TXP_COVERAGE
(
   SAT_CODE,
   ORBITAL_POSITION,
   TXP_NO,
   COVERAGE_DOWN,
   COVERAGE_UP,
   POLARIZATION_DOWN,
   POLARIZATION_UP
)
AS
     SELECT DISTINCT ##.OLB_AVAILABLE_TXP.SAT_CODE,
                     ###.SAT_DEP.ORBIT_LOC / 3600 ORBITAL_POSITION,
                     ##.OLB_AVAILABLE_TXP.TXP_NO,
                     ###.TXP.CUR_DN_COVERAGE COVERAGE_DOWN,
                     ###.TXP.CUR_UP_COVERAGE COVERAGE_UP,
                     ###.TXP.TXP_DN_POL,
                     ###.TXP.TXP_UP_POL

      ... The rest is omitted for clarity
```

The Hibernate entities are the following :

```
@Component(value = "viewOlbSatCoverage")
@Scope("prototype")
@Entity
@Table(name = "VIEW_OLB_SAT_COVERAGE", schema = "##")
public class ViewOlbSatCoverage implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6728959649786852446L;

    @Id
    private ViewOlbSatCoverageId viewOlbSatCoverageId;

    public ViewOlbSatCoverageId getViewOlbSatCoverageId() {
        return viewOlbSatCoverageId;
    }

    public void setViewOlbSatCoverageId(ViewOlbSatCoverageId viewOlbSatCoverageId) {
        this.viewOlbSatCoverageId = viewOlbSatCoverageId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ViewOlbSatCoverage : [viewOlbSatCoverageId=" + viewOlbSatCoverageId == null ? "null"
                : viewOlbSatCoverageId.toString() + "]";
    }
}

@Component(value = "viewOlbSatCoverageId")
@Scope("prototype")
@Embeddable
public class ViewOlbSatCoverageId implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2822316442843031126L;

    @Column(name = "COVERAGE_DOWN")
    private String coverageDown;

    @Column(name = "COVERAGE_UP")
    private String coverageUp;

    @Column(name = "SAT_CODE")
    private String satCode;

    @Column(name = "ORBITAL_POSITION")
    private BigDecimal orbitalPosition;

    public ViewOlbSatCoverageId() {

    }

    public ViewOlbSatCoverageId(String satCode, BigDecimal orbitalPosition, String coverageDown, String coverageUp) {
        setSatCode(satCode);
        setOrbitalPosition(orbitalPosition);
        setCoverageDown(coverageDown);
        setCoverageUp(coverageUp);
    }

// Getters, setters omitted for clarity ...
```

}

As I mentionned, the targetted database is Oracle 10g and all works fine with it (when the app is running). 
But when I run H2 database for unit testing purpose, the following method ( findDistinctAllOrbitalPositions) doesn't work :

```
    @Repository
    public class ViewOlbSatCoverageDaoImpl extends GenericDaoImpl<ViewOlbSatCoverage> implements ViewOlbSatCoverageDao {

        public ViewOlbSatCoverageDaoImpl() {
            setGenericClass(ViewOlbSatCoverage.class);
            setDaoLogger(ViewOlbSatCoverageDaoImpl.class);
        }

        @Override
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public List<BigDecimal> findDistinctAllOrbitalPositions() {
            Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(
                    "select distinct(viewOlbSatCoverageId.orbitalPosition) from " + genericClass.getSimpleName()
                    + " order by viewOlbSatCoverageId.orbitalPosition asc"); // genericClass is ViewOlbSatCoverage
            return query.list();
        }

}
```

As you can see, i'm using HQL but also the Criteria API.

When i launch maven from command line :

```
mvn clean -Dtest=ViewOlbSatCoverageDaoImplTestCase test
```

It gives me the following :

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "VIEWOLBSAT0_.ORBITAL_POSITION" not found; SQL state
ment:
select distinct viewolbsat0_.ORBITAL_POSITION as col_0_0_ from ##.VIEW_OLB_SAT_COVERAGE viewolbsat0_
 order by viewolbsat0_.ORBITAL_POSITION asc [42122-190]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
        at org.h2.expression.ExpressionColumn.optimize(ExpressionColumn.java:147)
        at org.h2.expression.Alias.optimize(Alias.java:51)
        at org.h2.command.dml.Select.prepare(Select.java:835)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:246)
        at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:460)
        at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:402)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1188)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:72)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:276)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler.continueInvocation(Connec
tionProxyHandler.java:138)
        ... 64 more
```

Here is a sample of my applicationContext-test.xml :

```
    <jdbc:embedded-database id="h2TestDataSource" type="H2"/>
        <jdbc:initialize-database data-source="h2TestDataSource">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:com/eutelsat/olb/sql/create/views/VIEW_OLB_SAT_COVERAGE.sql" />
<jdbc:script location="classpath:com/eutelsat/olb/sql/create/views/VIEW_OLB_TXP_COVERAGE.sql" />
        <!-- Other .sql files omitted for clarity -->
        </jdbc:initialize-database>

                                       <!-- Connection pool -->

    <bean id="pooledDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">       
        <property name="driverClass" value="org.h2.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:h2:mem:h2TestDataSource;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'com/eutelsat/olb/sql/create/schemas/INIT.sql'" />
        <property name="user" value="sa" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
        <property name="acquireIncrement" value="1" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="1" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="5" />
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="30" />
        <property name="maxIdleTimeExcessConnections" value="10" />
        <property name="numHelperThreads" value="3" />
        <property name="unreturnedConnectionTimeout" value="0" />
    </bean>

                                       <!-- Session factory -->

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="h2TestDataSource" />
      <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.eutelsat.olb.server.model" />
      <property name="hibernateProperties">
         <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">none</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">20</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.use_outer_join">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.order_inserts">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.order_updates">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">true</prop>
         </props>
      </property>
   </bean>

                                    <!-- Transaction Manager -->

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
```

I have read a lot of things but I can't find what the problem is (incorrect SQL script which needs to be adapted to fit in H2 database or maybe an H2 database config. with column alias matters ?).

NB : schemas have been obfuscated.

Thanks in advance for pointers.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution to my problem.
The SQL scripts (some of them were omitted in the sample posted in SOF) which were declared in my "applicationContext-test.xml" file were not well ordered resulting in a view with a INVALID status. 
-> Resulting in generated SQL query done by Hibernate complaining that some tables and / or columns were'nt found.

I've found the problem (and also the solution) thanks to the excellent H2 web server allowing me to view in memory data. In the SCHEMA_INFORMATION section, I saw VIEWS and when clicking on it, I saw STATUS = INVALID.

In order to add an H2 web server using Spring XML config, you can easily add this :

```
<bean id="h2Server" class="org.h2.tools.Server" factory-method="createTcpServer" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop" depends-on="h2WebServer">
        <constructor-arg value="-tcp,-tcpAllowOthers,-tcpPort,9992"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="h2WebServer" class="org.h2.tools.Server" factory-method="createWebServer" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
        <constructor-arg value="-web,-webAllowOthers,-webPort,8882"/>
    </bean>
```

**Do not forget to add a depends-on attribute valued to "h2Server" (so : depends-on="h2Server") to you datasource bean**, otherwise it will not work as expected !